# How to change image type of Photos drag and drop?

Tags: photos

When dragging and dropping *out* of Photos, it has the proprietary `HEIC` file type. This means we can't easily drag and drop onto many website/js upload fields. Instead we need to go through many steps — exporting, then uploading, then deleting the export file.

Is there a way to change drag-and-drop so that it auto-converts to a chosen image type, such as jpeg or png?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't replicate the issue. If I drag-and-drop from Photos into GitHub's new issue window everything works as expected. On iPhone I have Preferences > Camera > Formats set as High Efficency (HEIF/HEVC). If Most Compatible is selected it should default saving photos as jpeg.